# Why doesn't anything display on my react app once I put the Route in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6f7R.png)

Even though the Header is out the router it doesn't display.

Comment: Please post code directly here as text rather than a screenshot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `element` property of the `Route` to display the element in that route.

```
<Route path="/" element={<h1>This is homepage</h1>} />
```